# docker-compose / mysql: How to specify the volume correctly to use existing database

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I would like to containerize an existing mysql database linking the data directory inside my container to my local file system.

This docker run command works fine, i.e. the database is accessible and data is persisted.

```
docker run -v ./mydata:/var/lib/mysql mysql:5.7
```

However, I am unable to make it work with docker-compose.

I am getting the following errors

```
[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it. 
...
Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"
  services:
  database  :
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --port=4406
    volumes:
      - ./mydata:/var/lib/mysql
```

What is wrong with my compose-file?

UPDATE:
The content of mydata is

- auto.cnf
- ib_buffer
- pool
- ib_logfile0
- ib_logfile1
- ibdata1
- mysql

I also tried `./mydata/mysql:/var/lib/mysql` for volumes. That lets me connect to the db (through mysql workbench for instance), but I get the another error (DESCRIBE mysql.db File not found) when I try to see the users.

Comment: What do the contents of `/mydata` look like? Can you do an `ls`?

Comment: Thanks @Evert, yes, the contents of mydata is
auto.cnf  ib_buffer_pool  ib_logfile0  ib_logfile1  ibdata1  mysql

Comment: Is the user under which mysql runs able to access /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.* ?

Comment: Do you mean the files in the default location of the mysql server data directory? Yes, they are accessible. The also exist in the mydata directory (which is a copy of the original data directory) and inside the container.

Comment: perhaps a permission issue.  what is the ownership of the files/directory on your host?

Comment: Did you found your issue ? I'm facing the same one here.

Comment: @kev, it's been a long time and I don't remember exactly anymore. One potential solution was using absolute paths to specify the path to the my data folder. The other solution was uninstalling my anti virus programme.

Comment: @Zuabi : thank you for your answer. I'm using the absolute path. Today are you still using Docker with a mysql server? I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429086/docker-compose-mysql-import-an-existing-database-from-local-machine

Comment: @kev, no. I am not working on this project anymore